# In the VBA MS Project code, change the width of the task list area in the Gantt chart

Tags: vba, ms-project

When you open MS Project from another application, the Gantt chart chart closes most of the task list columns. How to change the width of the task list area in a Gantt chart in MS Project VBA code?

Comment: When you open a project, it is displayed how ever it was last saved, even when automated from another application. Not sure if there is a way in VBA to adjust the position of the divider between the task table and the Gantt chart.

Comment: A new (not saved) project opens and do not need to save it.
MS Project is used as an interface for editing a project, whose data is stored in another application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setSplitBar method.  i.e., ActiveProject.Application.SetSplitBar (15) will set the splitbar after 15 columns.  Or it will fit the splitbar as far to the right of the screen as it can and still be visible.